# How to read information about wifi connection from proc - net?

Tags: android, proc

Is there a way I can get information about my current WiFi connection on my android? Information like the name of the WiFi network, connection start time, connection duration etc.?

I looked inside the `proc/net` directory, but there too many other sub-directories and files, and I don't know where to start.